How to set the title and description of routes in the current nextjs?
Basically I'm facing the following error in the latest version of next, when using useEffect it says that I need to define "use client" at the top of the file, so far okay, but when I go to define the Head, it can't define the title or descriptions, then it recommends using metadata, but when using metadata, it returns the error because it says that it is not possible to use with the use client defined, then it stays in this loop. How to solve this?
I used it like this:
<Head>
<title>My Title</title>
<meta name="description" content="Site Description" />
</Head>

And now like this:
"use client"
export const metadatas = {
title: my title,
description: my description,
};

Just to answer, I don't know if this is the final solution, but it works for me, because in the old versions of Next I used Head without any problems, but since they updated it to this metadata and added a bunch of new details, it ended up messing up a bit for those who already used the old versions, because the problem is in this loop that they create, inside each route if you use useEffect you need to call 'use client', but to add the metadata in the specific route you can't use use client, so it creates a loop that I really couldn't understand. The only solution I found was one mentioned in this post How to define metadata for page.tsx rendered as client components. So it would be something like:

Just place the <title>, <meta> and <link> metadata tags anywhere in your component tree

"use client";
import { useState } from "react";

export default function Page() {

 const [title, setTitle] = useState("Hello World");

 return (
  <div>
    {/* Yes, we simply put the <title> tag anywhere in the document. */}
    <title>{title}</title>
    <input value={title} onChange={e => setTitle(e.target.value)} />
  </div>
 );
}

If anyone has another solution, feel free to share.

Define server-side metadata in the main route's file (page.tsx) using the metadata export.
Handle client logic by isolating components using "use client" where needed.
Don’t mix server logic and client logic, or you’ll hit these boundaries.

Please follow official Next.js documentation here.
App router: For setting metadata, you need to export and object or a function from page.tsx or layout.tsx file.

layout.tsx | page.tsx

import type { Metadata } from 'next'
 
// either Static metadata
export const metadata: Metadata = {
  title: '...',
}
 
// or Dynamic metadata
export async function generateMetadata({ params }) {
  return {
    title: '...',
  }
}

